# Rewrite $\cos (2 \sin^{-1}(4w))$ as an algebraic expression

Tags: trigonometry

How would I go about solving this? The program I use for school doesn't give great explanations. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried thinking about it geometrically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the formula $\cos(2x)=1 - 2\sin^2x$, and let $x=\arcsin(4w)$, so
$\sin x = 4w$.

After this substitution you get:
$$
\cos (2 \arcsin(4w)) = 1 - 2\sin^2x = 1-2\cdot(4w)^2 = 1 - 32w^2.
$$

Comment: For the inverse sine function, I am using $\arcsin$ rather than $\sin^{-1}$. This way we avoid the ambiguous situation where the superscript in $\sin^2...$ means "squared", while the superscript in $\sin^{-1}...$ means the inverse function.

Answer (score 0):

Define $\theta = \sin^{-1} 4w$.  Then $\cos 2\theta= 1-2 \sin^2 \theta$, and since $\sin \theta = 4w$, we have $\cos (2 \sin^{-1}(4w))= \cos 2 \theta = 1- 2 \sin^2 \theta = 1 - 32w^2$.

Answer (score 0):

given a right triangle:
assume

$\sin^{-1} (4w)=\theta$

(This may not be intuitive but it does set up the proof nicely)

$\sin(\sin^{-1} (4w)) = \sin(\theta)$

$4w = \sin(\theta)$

we know that
$\sin(\theta)$ is referring to the height of the aforementioned right triangle. Because $\sin(\theta)$ is the opposite divided by the hypotenuse, we take from $4w = \sin(\theta)$ that the opposite is 4w and the hypotenuse is 1. Now, since we are dealing with a right triangle, we use the pythagorean theorem: 
$(4w)^2+\alpha^2=1^2$ 
where $\alpha$ is the remaing face of the triangle (the face adjacent to $\sin(\theta)$ We the have:
$\alpha = \sqrt{1-16w^2}$
This is why we made our initial assumption to construct this right triangle: since $\cos(\theta)$ gives adjacent over hypotenuse, we have

$\cos(\sin^{-1} (4w)) = \cos(\theta) = \sqrt{1-16w^2} $

Because of the previously established fact:

$\theta = \sin^{-1} (4w)$

we have:

$\cos (2 \theta) = \cos( \sin^{-1} (4w))$
since

$\cos(2 \theta) = 2cos^2(\theta) -1$

it follows that

$\cos(2 \sin^{-1} (4w) = 2 (\sqrt{1-16w^2})^2 -1$

hence;

$\cos(2 \sin^{-1} (4w) = 2(1-16w^2)-1$

or

$\cos(2 \sin^{-1} (4w) = 1-32w^2$